# Nested possessives

Tags: possessives

Let's imagine the following situation:

My mom has a boyfriend and her boyfriend has a car.

I borrowed this car and I want to tell another person who is the owner of this car, I believe I have to use `'s` twice in this sentence:

> This is my mom's boyfriend's car.

Honestly I think that this is correct, but I am unsure if I can use the `'s` twice or more in this sentence, is this correct? Could I go even further than that?

> This is my mom's boyfriend's brother's car.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's fine. There is theoretically no limit on consecutive possessives; but of course at some point your reader is going to give up and go read something else!

Comment: Even in speech you have to eventually apologetically shrug as the list of possessives gets longer… & hope your audience either keeps up, or just sees the funny side. Wild gesticulation in an attempt to separate the relationships by mime is optional ;)

Comment: An overly long series of possessives is often used humorously to indicate that a rumor is untrustworthy.  "Did you hear about John and Mary?  Well my mother's sister's neighbor's son's best friend's doctor was there and she saw the whoooole thing."  The rumor-teller believes the rumor but the long list of possessives tells the reader that it is probably not true.  I just thought I'd add this as it's something you might run into sooner or later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, it works fine.

1. > my mom

   This is a noun phrase (NP).  The head is *mom*, and its determiner is *my*.

   > [my mom]'s

   We've added the genitive ***'s***, so now it's a genitive noun phrase.  Genitive NPs can be determiners in larger noun phrases:
2. > [my mom]'s boyfriend

   Now we've made a larger NP.  Its determiner is the genitive NP *[my mom]'s*, which we made in step one.

   > [[my mom]'s boyfriend]'s

   Now we've added the genitive ***'s*** again, so we've got a genitive NP again.
3. > [[my mom]'s boyfriend]'s brother

   This whole thing is an NP.  Its determiner is the genitive NP *[[my mom]'s boyfriend]'s*.

   > [[[my mom]'s boyfriend]'s brother]'s

   Now we've made it into a genitive NP.  Again.
4. > [[[my mom]'s boyfriend]'s brother]'s car

   This is another NP.  Its determiner is the genitive NP *[[[my mom]'s boyfriend]'s brother]'s*.

As you can see, we're repeating the same operations over and over.  You can do it as much as you like.  Eventually you'll probably amuse or confuse your conversation partner, though.